# How to append/concat pandas dataframes of stock prices into one large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

I have a list of 200 tickers which I'm trying to to import from csv into one large dataframe like this:

```
tickers = ['SPY', 'AAPL',]

for ticker in tickers:
    start = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 3)
    ticker1 = data.DataReader(ticker,'iex', start, end)
   
    stocks_prices = pd.concat([ticker1],axis=1,keys=tickers)
```

My `concat` code does not work, and it only shows prices for 'SPY'. Could someone please tell how to get it for 'AAPL' as well? I have a list of 200 stocks or so, want to merge it all together

Comment: You might want to try creating frames from ticker1 (representing 'SPY') and ticker2 (representing 'AAPL'). Ex. `frames = [ticker1, ticker2]`, then `stock_prices = pd.concat(frames)`

Comment: Yes but here i have only 2 stocks, when its 200 stocks. I have to manually write ticker1 to ticker200. Right?

Comment: like @haxtar said

Comment: Thanks guys. understood. will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
tickers = ['SPY', 'NVTR',]

frames=[]
for ticker in tickers:
    start = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 3)
    ticker1 = web.DataReader(ticker,'iex', start, end)
    frames.append(ticker1)

stocks_prices = pd.concat(frames,keys=tickers)
print(stocks_prices)
```

Outputs

> ```
>                    open     high     low   close    volume
>      date                                                 
> SPY  2018-10-01  292.11  292.930  290.98  291.73  62078937
>      2018-10-02  291.56  292.355  291.14  291.56  47258227
>      2018-10-03  292.74  293.210  291.32  291.72  64694594
> NVTR 2018-10-01   22.01   24.890   21.89   24.10    492424
>      2018-10-02   24.39   24.790   23.50   23.68    336636
>      2018-10-03   23.68   24.280   22.76   23.97    400894
> ```