# Creating Multiple Pandas Data Frames in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create a pandas data frame for each stock ticker in a list

My Code:

```
for ticker in stock_tickers:
   
     data = pd.read_csv(f'{ticker}_{get_date()}.csv')
```

it will only create one pandas data frame for the last stock ticker... is there anyway for this to be done all of them?

Comment: Create a list outside of the for loop and then `.append()` the newly created pandas dataframe

Comment: Can you give more details. You need one dataframe for all your csv files or you need a list of dataframes?

Comment: It's not *"only creating one pandas data frame for the last stock ticker"*, each iteration creates and overwrites each ticker's dataframe! When the loop finished, `data` just happens to be the last dataframe, the only one that didn't get overwritten. Really you need to read and [`pd.concat ()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) multiple dataframes, with an extra column for 'ticker'. Dataframes don't magically concatenate themselves, you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: Duplicate of [**How to append/concat pandas dataframes of stock prices into one large dataframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732739/how-to-append-concat-pandas-dataframes-of-stock-prices-into-one-large-dataframe). This question gets reasked once a month, please see existing duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You end up with only one data set because the `data` variable gets overwritten on every step of the loop.

You could store your data in a dictionary (assuming here that `ticker` is a string):

```py
data = {}

for ticker in stock_tickers:
    data[ticker] = pd.read_csv(f'{ticker}_{get_date()}.csv')
```

More compact version using a dict comprehension:

```py
data = {ticker: pd.read_csv(f'{ticker}_{get_date()}.csv')
        for ticker in stock_tickers}
```